# How to connect RSUs to Controller node via cable in omnet++ Veins?

Tags: omnet++, veins

I am trying to connect two (or more, in the future) RSUs (one is not in the transmission radius of the other) in the Controller node that will receive the information from the RSUs and build global knowledge of the scenario.

I've tried to approach as in the links [LINK1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54632111/error-when-connect-rsu-to-openflow-switch-in-omnet) and [LINK2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55761196/how-%20to-implement-rsu-to-rsu-communication-in-omnet-veins), and I was unsuccessful.

Is there a similar example?

PS: I am using Omnet++ 5.3, Veins 4.7.1, and Sumo 0.32.0.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how much focus you want to put on simulating the wired network, it might make sense to write your simulation as an INET simulation first and then use Veins (with its veins_inet submodule) to make nodes behave like vehicles.

Comment: My focus is on the vehicular part. But to have a centralized entity, I would like to have this node connected directly to the RSUs.

Comment: If information just needs to „magically“ get from module A to module B, feel free to apply what you learned in the Tic Toc tutorial to establish direct information exchange between modules. Or use C++ to have methods of one instance of a class change attributes of another instance.